# Recursive(Decimal to Hexadecimal) C++

Tags: c++, recursion, hex, decimal

I have this code.

```
void hexa(int dec, int y)
{

    int deci = dec % 16;
    dec /= 16;

    if (dec % 16, ++y)
    {
        cout << "A";
    }
    else if (dec % 16 == 11)
    {
        cout << "B";
        return;
    }
    else if (dec % 16 == 12)
    {
        cout << "C";
    }
    else if (dec % 16 == 13)
    {
        cout << "D";
    }
    else if (dec % 16 == 14)
    {
        cout << "E";
    }
    else if (dec % 16 == 15)
    {
        cout << "F";
    }
    cout << deci;
}
```

and I'm calling it in the `int main` as `hexa(dec);` and there's an error that says "Too few arguments in function call". Any ideas where I got wrong?

EDIT: Here's the whole code that I'm working on. It's a program that lets you convert decimal to binary, octal and hexa. and it includes the factorial conversion. If anyone is interested to help or to improve my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

void countdown();
void binary(int dec);
void octal(int dec);
void hexa(int dec, int y);
int a, y;

int factorial(int);

int main()
{
    int choice, choice2, dec;
    unsigned int n;
    cout << "[1] Factorial\n"
        << "[2] Coversion\n"
        << "[3] Exit\n";
    cin >> choice;
    switch(choice)
    {
    case 1:
        cout << "Enter a value: ";
        cin >> n;
        if(n <= 0)
        {
            cout << "Invalid input";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "\nThe Factorial of " << n << " is " << factorial(n);
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        cout << "Conversion\n"
            << "[4] Decimal to Octal\n"
            << "[5] Decimal to Binary\n"
            << "[6] Decimal to Hexadecimal\n";
        cin >> choice2;
        switch(choice2)
        {
        case 4:
            cout << "Enter the Decimal number: ";
            cin >> dec;
            if(dec < 0)
            {
                cout << "You entered a negative number\n";
            }
            octal(dec);
            system("pause>0");
            break;
        case 5:
            cout << "Enter the Decimal number: ";
            cin >> dec;
            if(dec < 0)
            {
                cout << "You entered a negative number\n";
            }
            binary(dec);
            system("pause>0");
            break;
        case 6:
            cout << "Enter the Decimal Number: ";
            cin >> dec;
            if(dec < 0)
            {
                cout << "You entered a negative number\n";
            }
            hexa(dec, y);
            break;
        }
    case 3: 
        cout << "\nThank you for using this program!\n"
            << "Press any key to exit...";
        system("exit");
        break;

    }
    system("pause>0");
}

/*int factorial(int a);
{
int i = a, rslt = 0;
if (n==1)
{
return 1;
}
else
{
n + factorial(n-1);
}
}*/

int factorial(int n)
{
   if (n == 0)
      return 1;
   return n * factorial(n - 1);
}

void binary(int dec) 
{
   int deci = dec % 2;
    dec /= 2;

    if (dec > 0)
    {
        binary(dec);
    }
    else if (dec = 0)
    {
        cout << "0";
        return;
    }

    cout << deci;
}

void octal(int dec)
{
    int deci = dec % 8;
    dec /= 8;

    if (dec > 0)
    {
        binary(dec);
    }
    else if (dec = 0)
    {
        cout << "0";
        return;
    }

    cout << deci;
}

void hexa(int dec, int y)
{

    int deci = dec % 16;
    dec /= 16;

    if (dec % 16 == 10)
    {
        cout << "A";
    }
    else if (dec % 16 == 11)
    {
        cout << "B";
        return;
    }
    else if (dec % 16 == 12)
    {
        cout << "C";
    }
    else if (dec % 16 == 13)
    {
        cout << "D";
    }
    else if (dec % 16 == 14)
    {
        cout << "E";
    }
    else if (dec % 16 == 15)
    {
        cout << "F";
    }
    cout << deci;
}
```

Comment: I don't mean to sound critical, but this code looks insane. Why not just something like `"0123456789ABCDEF"[dec % 16]`?

Comment: also there is no recursion.

Comment: My idea is that there are too few arguments in function call. Just a guess though.

Comment: I'm still new on how to convert decimal to hexadecimal but I'm done in Decimal to Octal, Decimal to Binary and I'm now confused. lol

Answer (score 2):

Your `hexa` function has two parameters, while you are passing only `dec` inside `main`.

Answer (score 0):

Your function takes to arguments, you call it with one.

Answer (score 0):

`void hexa(int dec, int y)` takes 2 args, and you are calling using `hexa(dec)` and passing only one argument

Answer (score 0):

You should overload `hexa` with a version that only takes one argument (as you need it within your main method) and calls the other version with a properly initialized `int y`. (I have no idea what you want do to with that `y` so I cannot tell you which value it is supposed to have in the beginning)

also you will need to recursively call the function to actually have a recursion.

also `if (dec % 16, ++y)` will not do what you might think it does. (and it is a terrible coding style)

there is an `else` missing before `cout << deci;` and you probably wanted to use `deci` inside the `if`s instead of `dec % 16` .....

furthermore you have a `switch` inside a `switch` which is rather evil. you want an `while(true)` loop around a single switch statement (deduplication of code) (or if you need several menus then put them into seperate functions).

the version in the comments `std::string("0123456789ABCDEF")[deci]` is of course the nicest solution to this, but even a switch statement

```
switch (deci) { 
case 10:
    std::cout << 'A';
    break;
case 11:
    ...
}
```

would be much nicer than the long if-elseif

inside `octal` you are calling `binary(dec)` instead of `octal(dec)`

Comment: I'm still new to coding and thanks a lot for your suggestions.